# change library dependencies in CMake build

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm building a library that depends on other static libraries, for testing, I have to change out one of the libraries for a test version. For the life of me I can't work out how to do this with CMake.

My CMake setup is something like the following:

```
add_library(X STATIC x.cpp)

add_library(Y STATIC y.cpp)

add_library(A STATIC a.cpp)
target_link_libraries(A X Y)

add_executable(EXE main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(EXE A)
```

This works fine, but now I want to create another executable that uses TEST_X instead of X. This is a simplified example, but I have a very complex dependencies from a legacy system.

So, how do I build a new executable linked with the different library (TEST_X instead of X)?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you correctly, you want an executable `TEST_EXE` depending on library `A`, which does not depend on library `X` but `TEST_X`, right?

I don't see any other way than creating a new library target `TEST_A` depending on `TEST_X` and not `X` and using this new `TEST_A` in a new executable `TEST_EXE`:

```
add_library(TEST_X STATIC test_x.cpp)
add_library(TEST_A STATIC a.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TEST_A TEST_X Y)
add_executable(TEST_EXE main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TEST_EXE TEST_A)
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct, this solution will work ... but I'd like to not have to define the extra TEST_A library.

Comment: What about wrapping the `X` library in a conditional and either define the _test_ version as the actual one or vice versa. I.e. without a change of the name, just other sources.

Answer (score 2):

If you set [`CMP0022`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0022.html) policy to `NEW`, "`INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` defines the link interface.". That allows you to manipulate library dependency at a later point through the [`INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.html) target property.

So in your case you can remove the dependency of `A` to `X` and add the wanted library dependency directly to your executable targets:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(ChangeLibDeps)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0022 NEW)

add_library(X STATIC x.cpp)
add_library(TEST_X STATIC test_x.cpp)

add_library(Y STATIC y.cpp)

add_library(A STATIC a.cpp)
target_link_libraries(A X Y)

get_target_property(_libs A INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES)
list(REMOVE_ITEM _libs X)
set_target_properties(A PROPERTIES INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES ${_libs})

add_executable(EXE main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(EXE A X)

add_executable(TEST_EXE main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TEST_EXE A TEXT_X)
```

Comment: In my case, I had to write `list( REMOVE_ITEM _libs "\$<LINK_ONLY:libname>" )`.